# can class data 'int'eger be refered by a list and then used 'for' a 'if' x>y

Tags: python, list, class, for-loop

I am having trouble referring to a class via a list and then comparing the integers for a required list output.

some examples of correct referencing would be appreciated or if  I'm trying to do something python cant do.

see example code below:

'''

```
#creating class
class class1: 
    def __init__(self, m, x, y, z): 
        self.m = m
        self.x = x #int
        self.y = y #int
        self.z = z #int

#creating list       
list = [] 
compare = []  

# appending instances to list 
list.append( class1( m, x, y, z) )
list.append( class1( m, x, y, z) )
list.append( class1( m, x, y, z) )

#comparison values
a=#int
b=#int
c=#int

#boolean
comparison=True
for obj in list:
    if obj.x > a:  
        comparison=False
     if obj.y > b:
        comparison=False
    if obj.z > c:
        comparison=False
    if comparison:
        compare.append (obj.m)
    else:
        print ()

print (compare)
```

'''

Comment: What is the issue? Does the code not work? If so, what's the error?

Comment: in the for ... in section. I dont know how to referece the data in the list above

Comment: One thing to note is that you are overriding a built-in. `list` is a reserved word in python and you are assigning it an empty list.

Comment: list was just to emphasize to myself what was being created. To get order right. list would not be used in actual code

Comment: I still don't understand, your for loop looks fine, does it not work correctly? `obj` refers to each list element as you iterate through the loop, and `obj.x` will refer to the `x` attribute of the object.

Comment: @BradDay To be pedantic, `list` is not a reserved word (if it were it would be a syntax error to even use it as a variable - `return` is a reserved word). But it is a built-in function and assigning a variable the name `list` shadows that built-in function, which is a bad thing and you are right to recommend against using it.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tried to clean up the code for you. I think I got what you were trying to do with the logic block at the very end. Hopefully this does what you wanted. The first `Class1` object appended to `mylist` is instantiated with all zeros which will cause all the comparisons to return false and therefore `obj.m` -> 0 will append to the `compare` list

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, m, x, y, z):
        self.m = m
        self.x = x  # int
        self.y = y  # int
        self.z = z  # int


# creating list
mylist = []
compare = []

# appending instances to list
mylist.append(Class1(0, 0, 0, 0))
mylist.append(Class1(2, 3, 4, 5))
mylist.append(Class1(3, 4, 5, 6))

# comparison values
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

# boolean
# I cleaned up the logic. Hopefully it's easier to understand
for obj in mylist:
    comparison = False
    if obj.x > a or obj.y > b or obj.z > c:
        comparison = True

    if not comparison:
        compare.append(obj.m)
        print("All comparisons were false")
    else:
        print("At least one comparsion is true")

print(compare)
```

Comment: thanks! the True / False, needed is reversed but ill give that a go!

Comment: Yah I flipped that but included a `not` in the final if clause to negate the flipping. I just found it easier to follow the logic when one of the comparisons returns true that the comparison variable would also be true . Either way hope it helps